# How can I access and download the Lock Screen image on my Iphone 13 Mini?

Tags: ios

There's a nice photo on the Lock Screen of my iPhone 13 Mini that I'd like to download in order to print it in its entirety (it's cropped when it appears on the lock screen).

How do I access the source image that ships with iOS?

Comment: Please edit this.  The custom photos are found in the files app or in the photos app and then get resembled as thumbnails, so I’m thinking you want to locate the original of a custom photo - not one that shipped from Apple based on comments

Comment: Ah. Custom pictures should be in your photo library.

Comment: Ummm... there are lots of photo's.   What I was hoping was that somewhere in the phone's filesystem there is a file named something like LockScreenImage that is soft-linked to the actual image, and that I could find it using *some* app.

Answer (score 1):

You don‘t say which specific wallpaper you are interested in, but searching for [ios wallpaper](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=ios+wallpaper) returns a lot of sites which offer wallpapers from various iOS versions for download.

Comment: thanks.   My understanding is that the "Lock Screen" appears when you first power on the iPhone (before the screen that requests a four-digit id).   On my phone (well, truthfully, on my wife's phone) there is a nice picture of our family that appears on her phone's Lock Screen, albeit somewhat cropped.   What I'm assuming is that this is actually a link to an (uncropped) photo file *somewhere* in the phone, which I could download to make a nice print